# Using glom, how can I concatenate optional strings?

Tags: python, glom

I have a dict containing a name in two parts:

```
target = {
    "givenName": "Elvis",
    "middleName": "Aron",
}
```

`middleName` is optional. I need to map to them one string, which is either `givenName + ' ' + middleName` if `middleName` is defined or just `firstName`. What is the canonical way to do this using `glom`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found so far is to use `lambda` and `Coalesce`. The below solution will work whether `middleName` is included or not:

```py
    glom(target, Coalesce(
            lambda t: t["givenName"] + " " + t["middleName"],
            "givenName",
            skip_exc=KeyError),
    )
```